# Trigger spinnaker pipeline

Tags: spinnaker

I have a problem with Automated spinnaker triggers with type Docker Registry.

My pipeline is successfully started when I don't write Tag setting and created new image with new tag and pushed it . But I need pipeline to be triggered when image with special tag is updated.

For example - when the image with Tag 'test' is appeared - pipeline should be started. I set up Tag setting - I wrote 'test' there - but when image with that tag is updated - my pipeline is not triggered.

There is a message from igor microservice:

`[RxIoScheduler-3] c.n.spinnaker.igor.docker.DockerMonitor  : Found 0 new images for dockerhub`

Is it possible to trigger pipeline if the image with appropriate tag is updated? I'll appreciate if you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `ImagePullPolicy` in the container settings in a Server Group is set to `IfNotPresent`, which means it won't trigger on an image change.

Try setting the `ImagePullPolicy` to "Always" in the container settings in the Server Group, and all changes to the image will trigger your pipeline in Spinnaker to run.